# Accessing C Structs Dynamically

Tags: c, dynamic, struct

I am trying to build a constructor-like function for structs in C. I'm best with languages built around object-oriented features, and adding object-oriented features to a bare-bones language is not my forte. Unfortunately, for this project, however, I am forced to use a variation of C.

The idea is to build a function with a parameter for each variable in the struct that needs to be initialized, along with a 'name' parameter for the name of the struct.

The biggest issue is that the variation of C I need to use is very limited in features. It doesn't seem to have dynamic memory allocation, among other things.

The goal code would be something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    string b;
} TheStruct;

void newStruct(string name, int a, string b){
    TheStruct name;
    name.a = a;
    name.b = b;
}
```

This won't work, because the struct instantiated with be called 'name' rather than the value of the name variable. How, without using higher-level features not found in C like variable variables, could a struct be dynamically referenced this way in C?

Comment: I'm afraid this does not make much sense... what are you trying to do with `name`?

Comment: [This book](http://www.planetpdf.com/codecuts/pdfs/ooc.pdf) seems to have some ideas about OOP in C.

Comment: Name is to be the name of the struct

Comment: The *name* of the struct? Put some extra code about how you intend to use this, since it's becoming even less clear :)

Comment: `It doesn't seem to have dynamic memory allocation` ????  Are you sure of that?  What compiler is that, some proprietary 80s abomination for embedded systems maybe starting with a K?

Comment: RobotC. The designers of the compiler and language tried to make it as child-safe as possible, and so all memory allocation is "handled" by the compiler and device firmware. It has a number of other weaknesses, too, but it's what I'm forced to use.

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist hmmm indeed - you could get around that by (ab)using arrays I guess.  But as this language's capabilities seem to be seriously trimmed down wrt "full" C I think you better stick to the basics - otherwise I'd suggest to have a look a various HashMap alike collections that exist in C because they offer functionality that should more or less give you what you seem to want, but I'm not sure it's possible to implement these in RobotC, the thing just isn't designed for that kind of wild programming.

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist I love being proven wrong: http://www.robotc.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=4464&view=previous - a HashMap for RobotC

Comment: You shuold also take a look here how OOP is implemented in C. http://ooc-coding.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

Two choices:

1. pass an `struct TheStruct` by reference to the `newStruct` method
2. return a heap allocated struct (a pointer to a `struct TheStruct` from `newStruct`) which later you'll have to delete using `free`

The method could be something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    string b;
} TheStruct;

void newStruct(TheStruct* st, string name, int a, string b){
    st->a = a;
    st->b = b;
}
```

or

```
TheStruct* newStruct(string name, int a, string b){
    TheStruct *res = malloc(sizeof(TheStruct));
    res->a = a;
    res->b = b;
    return res;
}
```

You can take a look at this tutorial which is very nice: [Pointers in C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/). Is for C++ but the basics are pretty much the same.

Comment: please don't cast the result of malloc

Comment: What's the best way to do it then in C?

Comment: In C you leave it out completely. A `void *` is implicitly converted to the type of the lvalue.  Casting the result of `malloc()` potentially leads to subtle hidden errors when the definition of `malloc()` is implicit (K&R style for example).  For a complete (and better explanation than I can do) see http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't knew this, updating the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass a `TheStruct` in by reference or return a pointer to a new struct.

```
void newStruct( TheStruct* s, int a, string b )
{
   if( !s )
      s = malloc( sizeof( TheStruct ) );

   s->a = a;
   s->b = b;
}

//or

TheStruct* newStruct( int a, string b )
{
    TheStruct* s = malloc( sizeof( TheStruct ) );
    s->a = a;
    s->b = b;
    return s;
}
```

NOTE: when using the second version, you will have to remember to clean up the memory since it is created on the heap. With the first version, `TheStruct` could be created on the stack or the heap. (I assume a and b are defined.)

```
TheStruct s1, *s2;
s2 = malloc( sizeof( TheStruct ) );
newStruct( &s1, a, b );
newStruct( s2, a, b );
// do stuff
free( s2 );
```

In the second version it would look like:

```
TheStruct *s3 = newStruct( a, b );
// do stuff
free( s3 );
```

Comment: For the first version, C doesn't have pass-by-reference, only pass-by-pointer. Sorry for pedantry. :-)

Comment: ah really. Haven't used C in too long i guess. Updated.